# Modifying Hooker Logic: Wordpress and Instant Articles

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

The following code runs inside of the Facebook Instant Articles plugin by Automattic. It is the query used to generate the RSS feed that facebook pulls for instant articles.

```
function instant_articles_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_feed( INSTANT_ARTICLES_SLUG ) ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 100 );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_rss', 100 );
        $settings_categories = Instant_Articles_Option_Categories::get_option_decoded();
        if($settings_categories['categories'] !== '') {
            $query->set( 'cat', $settings_categories['categories'] );
        }
        /**
         * If the constant INSTANT_ARTICLES_LIMIT_POSTS is set to true, we will limit the feed
         * to only include posts which are modified within the last 24 hours.
         * Facebook will initially need 100 posts to pass the review, but will only update
         * already imported articles if they are modified within the last 24 hours.
         */
        if ( defined( 'INSTANT_ARTICLES_LIMIT_POSTS' ) && INSTANT_ARTICLES_LIMIT_POSTS ) {
            $query->set( 'date_query', array(
                array(
                    'column' => 'post_modified',
                    'after'  => '1 day ago',
                ),
            ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'instant_articles_query', 10, 1 );
```

I need to modify the query that this runs to take a meta query but I need to do so outside of the plugin file. I know that hooks are the way to go but is it possible or correct to do the following?

```
function mod_ia_query( $query ) {

   $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    array(
          'key' => 'is_instant_article',
          'value' => true
    ),
   );


}
add_action('instant_articles_query','mod_ia_query', 10, 1);
```

Comment: Does the plugin define a hook called `instant_articles_query`? Looks rather like you just used the function name here, which will of course not work. You should use the same hook as the plugin does – `pre_get_posts` – with the priority set so that it gets executed after the function of the plugin. And you need to perform the same checks for what type of query it is as the plugin function does, otherwise you will be manipulating different queries that have nothing to do with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming back to update this but essentially what I did was create a subdirectory in my theme with the name of the facebook instant articles plugin and create a class that extends the `Instant_Articles` Class.

I unhooked the `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'instant_articles_query', 10, 1 );`

And added my own method to the hook, this performs my functionality within the context of the plugin but without directly editing core plugin files.